# Crystal-Lang - Cross-Macro Macro-variables

Tags: crystal-lang

So I'm building a data type where, I would like, **optional auto-casting**. [The last question I asked is related to this also.](http://...)

The code I currently have can be found below:

```
class Test(T)
  @@auto_cast = false

  def initialize(var : T)
    @var = var
  end
  def self.auto_cast
    @@auto_cast
  end
  def self.auto_cast=(val)
    @@auto_cast = val
  end

  def self.auto_cast(forced_value=true,&block)
    #Force value, but store initial value:
    ac = @@auto_cast
    @@auto_cast = forced_value
      block.call
    @@auto_cast = ac
  end

  def +(val)
    var = @var
    if @@auto_cast
      if var.is_a? String
        casted_arg = val.to_s
        return var + casted_arg
      else
        casted_arg = typeof(var).new(val)
        return var + casted_arg
      end
    else
      if typeof(var) != typeof(val)
        {{raise "Error: Type of <<var>> is not equal to type of <<val>> while auto_cast is false."}}
      else
        return var + val
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to test the data type however:

```
Test.auto_cast do
  puts Test.auto_cast
  puts Test.new(1) + "1"
  puts Test.new("1") + 1
end
```

It throws an error at `return var + val`:

```
  if typeof(var) != typeof(val)
    {{raise "Error: Type of <<var>> is not equal to type of <<val>> while auto_cast is false."}}
  else
    ERROR! --> return var + val
  end
```

At first I was confused why, but now it makes sense.

1. I believe the Crystal compiler cannot be certain that `@@auto_cast` will be true whenever I intend to auto_cast (and to be fair, when auto-casting is disabled, I want the syntax error).
2. A compile error occurs because the value of `@@auto_cast` is unknown at compile time.
3. Due to the contradictory nature of the bodies:

.

```
if var.is_a? String
  casted_arg = val.to_s
  return var + casted_arg
else
  casted_arg = typeof(var).new(val)
  return var + casted_arg
end
```

and

```
  if typeof(var) != typeof(val)
    {{raise "Error: Type of <<var>> is not equal to type of <<val>> while auto_cast is false."}}
  else
    return var + val
  end
```

Each definition should only be used when the user explicitly declares it. Thus this is more suited to a macro.

Given these reasons I started trying to build the functionality into a macro instead:

```
  def +(val)
    var = @var
    {%if @@auto_cast%}
      if var.is_a? String
        casted_arg = val.to_s
        return var + casted_arg
      else
        casted_arg = typeof(var).new(val)
        return var + casted_arg
      end
    {%else%}
      if typeof(var) != typeof(val)
        {{raise "Error: Type of <<var>> is not equal to type of <<val>> while auto_cast is false."}}
      else
        return var + val
      end
    {%end%}
  end
```

I thought this would work because, this way code is only ever generated if `@@auto_cast` is set. However what I forgot was premise #2. I.E. the value of `@@auto_cast` is unknown at compile time. Ultimately, in order to make this work I would need a variable which can be:

1. Set at compile time.
2. Used globally within macros at compile time.

Ultimately I figured I could do something along the lines of this:

```
SET_AUTOCAST_VARIABLE true
  puts Test.auto_cast
  puts Test.new(1) + "1"
  puts Test.new("1") + 1
SET_AUTOCAST_VARIABLE false
```

and then in the `+()` definition:

```
{%if autocast_variable %}
   ...
{%else%}
   ...
{%end%}
```

The problem is, I do not think such a *macro global variable* exists... I was thinking about ways to get around this issue and so far the only solution I can come up with is using some external file at compile time:

```
{{File.write("/tmp/cct","1")}}
  puts Test.auto_cast
  puts Test.new(1) + "1"
  puts Test.new("1") + 1
{{File.write("/tmp/cct","")}}
```

and in the method definition:

```
{%if File.read("/tmp/cct")=="1" %}
   ...
{%else%}
   ...
{%end%}
```

This feels really hacky though... I was wondering whether there were any other alternatives, (or, even, if this just won't work at all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't work. Methods are only instantiated once, it is not possible to have two implementations of the same method with the same argument types. In the following example both `+` methods will inevitably have the same implementation.

```
Test.auto_cast do
  Test.new(1) + "1"
end
Test.new(1) + "1"
```

You can't have different implementations of *the same* method depending on lexical scope. The method is exactly instantiated once and so is the macro inside it.

I don't understand your overall use case, but maybe there are other ways to achieve what you need.

---

For completeness: You can utilize a constant as a *macro global variable*. Constants can't be redefined, but altered through macro expressions. That can be used to store state between macros. For example:

```
FOO = [true]
{{ FOO[0] }} # => true
{% FOO.clear; FOO << false %}
{{ FOO[0] }} # => false
```

That's pretty hacky, though ;)

Comment: It did cross my mind that methods may be instantiated only once. And I actually clarified it later with the method I suggested last. It's a shame, but it's fine also. It was only really for 'syntax sugar'. Another idea I did have is to have 2 separate classes which extend the same base class but implement `+()` differently, then at compile time choose which class to instantiate variables on based on a variable.  But then again it may just be better for users to straight up use the class.